# How can i refactor this Ruby, Rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I'm new at Rails... Is there a better way to refactor this code:

```
  def get_product_price_minimum
    Product.minimum(:price).to_i
  end

  def get_product_price_maximum
    Product.maximum(:price).to_i
  end
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this two methods, so I can give solution based on purpose.
e.g. you want minimum price product

Comment: Why are those two methods a problem? Sure, you could mash them together but to what end? Would refactoring make the code easier to read? Easier to use? Easier to debug? Easier to test? Faster? Maybe move them to class methods on `Product` and call it a day. Refactoring is great but there's not enough there to make it worthwhile (IMO).

Answer (score 2):

You can define something like "prices" (a vague method name, to avoid using get_ or set_ prefixes) to expect an argument, which would be the maximum or minimum for which to query your model:

```
def prices(what)
  Product.public_send(what, :price).to_i
end
```

Then you can use it by passing the minimum or maximum as a symbol or a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your function works
but you can try (if price is column and price is a int not a string)

```
def get_product_price_minimum
      Product.order('price').last
end
```

Comment: what about maximum?